# ui-select databinding not working in directive

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I have angular-ui/ui-select working fine as below:

```
ui-select(multiple="" name="resourceSelector" ng-model="appointmentTemplate.resources")
    ui-select-match(placeholder="Select Resources")
        span {{$item.name}}
    ui-select-choices(repeat="resource in resources | filter: {name:$select.search}")
        div {{resource.name}}
```

When `appointmentTemplate.resources` is populated like when the view loads, the resource shows as it should in the element.

I have tried to wrap it in a directive (my first). The directive won't show the supplied `appointmentTemplate.resources`. I can select new ones and save them fine, just not display the existing ones. I have confirmed the data is there using ng-inspector. Here is the directive controller:

```
angular.module('app').directive('resourceMultiSelector', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            ngModel: '=',
            placeholder: '@'
        },
        controller: function($scope, zResource, $sce){
            zResource.query(function(resources){
                $scope.resources = resources;
            });
        },
        templateUrl: "/partials/common/resourceMultiSelector"
    };

});
```

And here is the directive template (in Jade):

```
ui-select(multiple="" ng-model="$parent.ngModel")
    ui-select-match(placeholder="{{placeholder}}")
        span {{$item.name}}
    ui-select-choices(repeat="resource in resources | filter: {name:$select.search}")
        div {{resource.name}}
```

I use the directive like this:

```
resource-multi-selector(ng-model="appointmentTemplate.resources" placeholder="Select resources" )
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Duh. So the objects in the list need to be from the list of choices, not just identical, but the same actual object. Obvious in retrospect I guess :/